# ¿Como puedo ejecutar un controlador sin abrir la vista?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Estoy trabajando con AngularMaterial específicamente con `$mdDialog` cuando entro al dialogo mi controlador trabaja, ahora lo que necesito es poder ejecutar el controlador sin abrir la view del dialogo.
esta es la funcion que contiene el `mdDialog`

```
 vm.showAdvanced = function (ev, rowEmployee) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: DialogController,
            templateUrl: 'dialog-liqui.tmpl.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            fullscreen: true,
            locals: {
                employee: employee
            }
};
```

¿Como puedo ejecutar el controlador y pasarle ademas los datos de locals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo utilizando los servicios `$rootScope` y `$controller`.

`$rootScope` para crearle un nuevo scope al controlador que quieres ejecutar y el `$controller` para que injecte los servicios que el controlador demanda:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("Ctrl1", function($scope, $rootScope, $controller){
  $scope.mensaje = "Precioname!";
  $scope.cargarCtrl = function(){
     // le asignamos un nuevo scope
     var $ctrlNewScope = $rootScope.$new();
     
     // le asignamos el locals al nuevo scope
     $ctrlNewScope.employee = {nombre: "einer" };
     
     // ejecutamos el controllador 
     $controller(DialogController,{ $scope : $ctrlNewScope });
  }
});

function DialogController($scope, $timeout){

  console.log("eejecutando segundo controllador!");
  console.log("el valor del emeployee es :"); 
  console.log($scope.employee);
  $timeout(function(){
    console.log("el controlador esta injectando los servicios perfectamente!");
  },2000);
  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
  
  <button ng-click="cargarCtrl()">{{mensaje}}</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

No se para que quieres solo inicializar un controlador sin ninguna vista cuando puedes utilizar un servicio pero ya eso seria tu decisión.

Comment: si utilizo un servicio, debo poner el mdDialog dentro de ese servicio o solo el controller?

Comment: Solo la lógica del controlador ya que no necesitas la vista.

Comment: entonces inyecto el servicio en controller del mdDialog https://pastebin.com/rfWA0aU5

Comment: Cuando tenga acceso una pc te muestro el ejemplo.

Comment: ok, como muestra en el codigo estoy pasando el servicio en el controller del mdDialog , funciona pero el parametro employee de locals no pasa al servicio

Comment: de acuerdo a tu codigo, si dentro del controlador DialogController  hay una funcion que solo se ejecuta desde la view, y quiero ejecutarla, como tendra que hacerlo

Comment: Puedes explicarte un poco mejor? No entiendo lo que quieres decir.

Comment: disculpa la patudes, exite la pcosibilidad de comunicarme contigo por otro medio

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66373/discussion-between-einer-and-luis-ruiz-figueroa).